# Error on delete voyager role it is already assigned to user

Tags: php, laravel

I am using voyager admin panel.
I am trying to delete permission role, which already assigned to the user, then voyager give me an error:

> 2020-02-19 11:07:56] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails (`data_base_name`.`users`, CONSTRAINT
>   `users_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles`
>   (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `roles` where `id` = 4)

voyager should show me a message that role can not delete its assigned to the user.

Comment: I don't understand the question: You expect an error and this is what you get. What's the problem?

Comment: Doesn't the error message say exactly that? It indicates that the role cannot be deleted as that would violate the constraint on the users table? It is likely that the role_id field on users table cannot be null? Therefore the role cannot be removed as it would require the field to be set to null or it would require the deletion of all users with role_id=4 (also not what you would want I presume)

Comment: @mtholen so it is migration issue, we should need to remove delete cascading from migration?

Comment: @shazimali I would not be in a position to advise on that as I do not have sufficient information to judge whether you should or shouldn't remove the cascading. That was not the question? An error message comes back which correctly identifies the problem, up to you how to handle that message?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    try {
        return parent::destroy($request, $id);
    } catch (QueryException $exception) {
        $message = $exception->getMessage();
        if (strpos($message, 'foreign key constraint') !== false) {
            $message = "This row can't be deleted";
        }

        return back()->with(['message' => $message]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `try-catch` for something like this. Since it's a foreign key assigned to another record then it is expected behaviour not to be able to delete it.

Since you create a message out of the error you should do something like:

```
try { 
  //query goes here
} catch(\Exception $e){ 
 $error = $e->getMessage();
 return $error;
}
```

Comment: ye but not more briefly.

Comment: What do you mean? You can always return a custom response by your self like:

`return response()->json('Role is already assigned to a user',403);` Instead of returning the error message